# Dynamic sampling of thermal images

Tags: algorithms

My master’s dissertation subject is to analyze and implement an algorithm that would sample thermal images from camera with different frequency rates to optimize database size and processing power.

Is anyone aware of any publication related to this subject? It seems that I cannot find any information on sampling patterns for raw 2d data streams, nor algorithms that would detect or calculate if the image differs enough from previous ones and is worth capturing.

Comment: You might get better answers on [dsp.se] or [electronics.se].

Comment: Before you take this question to a different site you should also try to add some more details to your question.  What are you trying to achieve?  Is the goal to use less storage or to use less energy?  Have you looked into PCA and auto-encoders, and other dimensionality reduction techniques?  Do you need lossless compression?  Have you looked into compression?  What (if anything) have you concluded on these topics?

Comment: @PålGD thanks for answer, during reasearch I've looked into compression techniques which seems to be commonly used in this type of reasearch but the goal is to develop dynamic sampling pattern without altering data structure